# VivaGraphJS - webGL line thickness

Tags: javascript, webgl, vivagraphjs

Is there anyway to change the line thickness default value?

I know that unfortunately there isn't any method to change the line specifications dynamically. Only color can be changed. But if someone knows a way to change the line thickness, it would be very helpful.